# Is there a way to parse minecraft command style JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, minecraft

Minecraft's JSON parsing is extremely loose. JSON that Minecraft considers OK cannot be parsed as valid JSON, nor as YAML, nor can it be directly evaluated as Python code.

JSON crimes that Minecraft parses fine include:

1. Allowing single-quotes `'` instead of double-quotes `"`. (And therefore not requiring double-quotes inside single-quotes to be escaped.)
2. Allowing unquoted keys
3. Allowing unquoted string values.

Thus, Minecraft considers the following valid:
`{foo:bar,'foo2':'bar "foobar"'}`

Is there any easy way of coaxing python to decode this in to a dict, short of writing my own parser?

I have already tried the demjson and dirtyjson modules, which both fail on point 3.

Comment: there is module `dirtyjson` which maybe could handle it.

Comment: I tested your example with dirtyjson and it handles 1. and 2. but not 3.

Answer (score 1):

To use a string variable which contains `'` and `"`, you need to use triple-doubleqoutes in Python. Then you can remove all quotes and then use regex to wrap all the parts again with `"` quotes.

```
import re
datastr = r"""{foo:bar, 'foo2':'bar "foobar"', 'foo3':"bar 'foobar' "barfoo"}"""

# remove all quotes
datastr = datastr.replace("'", "")
datastr = datastr.replace('"', '')
datastr = datastr.replace(", ", ",")
# >> datastr is now {foo:bar,foo2:bar foobar,foo3:bar foobar barfoo}

# wrap parts with quotes
datastr = re.sub(r"([\w|\s]+):([\w|\s]+)", r'"\1":"\2"', datastr)
# >> datastr is now {"foo":"bar","foo2":"bar foobar","foo3":"bar foobar barfoo"}
```

This covers all possibilities you mentioned (and more as it would also fix irregularites/whitespaces/quotes in the json keys). If this doesn't work for the whole dataset, maybe take a look at packages like https://pypi.org/project/demjson/

Comment: This kills the quotes inside the foo2 and foo3 strings, which may not be ideal. (Although this may be a good solution if you don't mind that, and you don't want to write a parser.)

Comment: I need to maintain the quotes inside strings.

I have also already tried demijson, sorry I should have noted that in the question. I have edited to add that info.